# PHP: how to make new object of class with name stored in member string?

Tags: php, reflection

So I want to do something like this:

```
$ob = new $this->other_class_name;
```

but it fails. How can I do it without storing other_class_name in local variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the name in another variable:

```
$class = $this->other_class_name;
$ob = new $class;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$class = get_class($this->other_class_name);
$ob = new $class;
```

Comment: Isn't `$this->other_class_name` a string and not an object?

Comment: by the info given i thought it was an object of the type 'other_class_name' if it is a string it's even easier

Comment: Yes... but if you have already an object, you don't even need to create one from a string. You could use the clone method.